# ML Kit ASR error: Error code:40,subError code:3005,errorMessage: Service unavailable

Tags: android, kotlin, machine-learning, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ml-kit

I've been developing a demo for speech recognition and ran into an issue. Could anyone help me?  I called `startRecognizing` interface and received an onError callback (Error 11203, subError 3005, errorMessage: service unavailable), see screenshot:

I followed the [document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/ml-asr-0000001050066212#section1232432143314) , My code:

```
// Create an Intent to set parameters.
val mSpeechRecognizerIntent = Intent(MLAsrConstants.ACTION_HMS_ASR_SPEECH)
// Use Intent for recognition parameter settings.
mSpeechRecognizerIntent 
// Set the language that can be recognized to English. If this parameter is not set, English is recognized by default. Example: "zh-CN": Chinese; "en-US": English; "fr-FR": French; "es-ES": Spanish; "de-DE": German; "it-IT": Italian; "ar": Arabic; "th_TH": Thai; "ms_MY": Malay; "fil_PH": Filipino.
.putExtra(MLAsrConstants.LANGUAGE, "en-US") // Set to return the recognition result along with the speech. If you ignore the setting, this mode is used by default. Options are as follows:
// MLAsrConstants.FEATURE_WORDFLUX: Recognizes and returns texts through onRecognizingResults.
// MLAsrConstants.FEATURE_ALLINONE: After the recognition is complete, texts are returned through onResults.
.putExtra(MLAsrConstants.FEATURE, MLAsrConstants.FEATURE_WORDFLUX) // Set the application scenario. MLAsrConstants.SCENES_SHOPPING indicates shopping, which is supported only for Chinese. Under this scenario, recognition for the name of Huawei products has been optimized.
.putExtra(MLAsrConstants.SCENES, MLAsrConstants.SCENES_SHOPPING)
// Start speech recognition.
mSpeechRecognizer.startRecognizing(mSpeechRecognizerIntent)
```

Do you have any idea why this could be happening? Please help, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `"en-US"` to `"zh-CN"`.

Or comment out `".putExtra(SCENES, SCENES_SHOPPING)"`:

[image]